# an enigma i can't solve, could you please help me solve it

Tags: cipher

> Xnt vhkk rshk rghmhmf dudm vgdm hs fdsr czgj

could you please help me crack this enigma, someone sent it to me a few days ago and i can't stop thinking about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a weid message of some sort via a Caesar Cipher.
 It says

> you will stil shining even when it gets dahk
>  It has a Caesar shift of 1. I don't understand what it means though

Comment: How would a X to Y shift be 6 on 1st letter? To me it seems a clear rotate 1.

Comment: @DanteTheSmith, that was a typo, sorry. I meant to put 1. I've edited it.

Answer (score 2):

> ROT 1 ->  You will stil shining even when it gets dahk

Could it possibly be someone is not literate in English as they might think or they made mistakes manually rotating the letters?

I would take a guess and say the message is to be conveyed as:

> You will still shine even when it gets dark.
>  Rot 1 is basically rotated every English latter by 1 ahead, so A is B, b is c and Z is A.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Could you edit your answer to include spoiler tags, so as to avoid potentially spoiling the solution for anyone who wants to have a go at the puzzle themselves?

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to figure out the format, not so intuitive like stackoverflow ones ;)